# Recalculating area of single field in another projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, area

I have polygon area. ArcGIS automatically calculate it's area for current coordinate system. I would like to create second field and calculate it's area in another coordinate system.

So in result I would like have two fields with two different coordinate system.

Is it possible to do in ArcGIS? Only for field, no changing projection of all data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Add a new field, then in the attribute table, right click on the field name and use "calculate geometry". You'll have the option to choose your units of measure and reference coordinate system (source data or current data frame). If necessary, temporarily modify your data frame coordinate system to get the job done.

See [ArcMap: Calculating area, length, and other geometric properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm)

Comment: I need to change layer coordinate system. I need to do it's with Model Builder. So I do not think that it would be possible to specify layer parameter there, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you require model builder, you should add that as a tag to your question. For that you will be required to use the "Add Geometry Attributes" tool as described by @GISGe.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ArcGIS 10.2.1 or above, you can use the [Add Geometry Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000191000000) tool. You can choose the coordinate system you want to use, and also the units, so they can be different from the units of your input's coordinate system. No need to add fields in advance, the tool does it for you.

Beware, if your input's coordinate system and the desired coordinate system have a different datum, you will need to specify a datum transformation in the tool's environments.